# Select value with check if between two values

Tags: excel

I have the following table in excel:

```
   0    1150    0.27
1151    1200    0.26
1201    1250    0.24
1251    1300    0.24
1301    1350    0.23
1351    1400    0.22
1401    1450    0.21
1451    1500    0.2
1501    1550    0.2
1551    1600    0.19
```

Now I am looking for a formula which is taking a value from a cell (I24), looks if it between the first and second value of the table and returns the third value. For example when the value of I24 is 1275 the formula should return 0.24

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? This site thrives on feedback. If any worked please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer. If they did not work please let us know what went wrong so we can better the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few options

**LookUp**

```
= LookUp( I24, A:C )
```

This will work with your sample data, but like `VLOOKUP` it will compare only the values in the first column and will ignore the values in the second column. It will result in `0.19` for any value greater or equal to `1551`, and in `#N/A` error for any value below `0`.

**SumProduct**

```
= SumProduct( (A:A <= I24) * (I24 <= B:B) * C:C )
```

The result is the sum of all values that match the conditions, but in your case only one row will match the condition and the rest will result in 0.

**Index and Match array formula**

```
= Index( C:C, Match( 1, (A:A <= I24) * (I24 <= B:B), 0 ) )
```

This array formula solution has to be entered with Ctrl + Shift + Enter instead of just Enter. It will result in `#N/A` error for any value that is not in the range, so it can be combined with the `IfError` function to specify the value when there is no match:

```
= IfError( Index( C:C, Match( 1, (A:A <= I24) * (I24 <= B:B), 0 ) ), 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table starts on `Column A` and the value you mentioned is in `I24`:

```
=IF(AND(I24>A24,I24<B24),C24, "")
```

Comment: This would only pick up if it matched the first range, and not which range it matches?

Answer (score 0):

Use [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):

```
=VLOOKUP(I24,A:C,3)
```

This will find where the value in I24 is greater than or equal to, and less than the next in Column A.  Column B if it does not overlap Column As value is not needed.

[image]

Comment: This would only produce the value if it matched the first column, not if it was between first and second as was requested

Comment: @Gallus without the last criterion this will find the value as requested. I hope you tried it before down voting.

Comment: @Gallus the fourth criterion is optional and defaults to true,  It is not needed when the column is sorted and a relative lookup is wanted.

Comment: There is no context in the answer though... that information would have been useful to explain to the OP why it worked, rather than just a copy paste formula. I have to admit, I forgot it defaulted to True, so I've removed the down vote as it does at least work.

Comment: There was enough information that if the OP or any other person coming after could do a simple search on VLOOKUP and find much more and better information than I could provide in this setting.  I have been doing this for a while as my rep  will attest,  I put in as much effort in my answer as the OP does in finding one.